# R: Add text to plots in lower rightern corner outside plot area

Tags: r, text, plot

I am plotting multiple graphs in baseR and I am trying to plot a text in the lower rightern corner of my plots. I tried using `mtext()` but this doesn't give me the desired result. How would you do this? The idea in the end is to generate something like the graphic below. How could I do this?

[image]

Here is my code I use to generate the plots.

```
xy <- data.frame(NAME=c("NAME1", "NAME1","NAME1","NAME1","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2"),ID=c(47,47,47,47,259,259,259),YEAR=c(1932,1942,1965,1989,2007,2008,2014),VALUE=c(0,NA,-6,-16,0,-9,-28), test=c("text1","text1","text1","text1","text2","text2","text2"))

# split data by index 
ind <- split(x = xy,f = xy[,'ID'])

plot1 <- function(x) {
  fname <- paste0(x[1, 'ID'], '.png')
  png(fname, width=1679, height=1165, res=150)
  par(mar=c(6,8,6,5))
  plot(x = c(1946, 2014),
       y = range(x$VALUE, na.rm=TRUE),
       type='n',
       main=x[1, 'NAME'],
       xlab="Time [Years]",
       ylab="Value [m]")
  axis(2, at = seq(-100000, 100000, 100), cex.axis=1, labels=FALSE, tcl=-0.3)
  points(x[,c('YEAR','VALUE')], type="l", lwd=2)
  points(x[,c('YEAR','VALUE')], type="p", lwd=1, cex=0.5, pch=21, bg='white')
  abline(h=0)
  mtext(x$test, side=1, )

  dev.off()
}

plot2 <- function(x) {
  fname <- paste0(x[1, 'ID'], '.png')
  png(fname, width=1679, height=1165, res=150)    
  par(mar=c(6,8,6,5))
  plot(x[,c('YEAR','VALUE')],
       type='n',
       main=x[1, 'NAME'],
       xlab="Time [Years]",
       ylab="value [m]")
  axis(2, at = seq(-100000, 100000, 100), cex.axis=1, labels=FALSE, tcl=-0.3)
  points(x[,c('YEAR','VALUE')], type="l", lwd=2)
  points(x[,c('YEAR','VALUE')], type="p", lwd=1, cex=0.5, pch=21, bg='white')
  abline(h=0)
  mtext(x$test, side=1)
  dev.off() 
}

lapply(ind, function(x) ifelse(any(x$YEAR < 1946 & x$YEAR < 2014), plot2(x), plot1(x)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
plot(1)
title(sub="hallo", adj=1, line=3, font=2)
```

Comment: this is a great solution, however is there a way I could make it look (font, font size etc) than the default xlab and ylab? E.g. make the title look plain?

Comment: It is possible to add cex.sub = 0.75 option to control font size

Answer (score 22):

With `mtext()` you can put your text at plot margin. In your case, you can try playing with parameters `line` and `at`. See [`help(mtext)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/mtext.html)

```
plot(1:10,10:1)
mtext('text is here', side=1, line=3.5, at=9)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, I already tried this but the problem is that when I plot (multiple plots, not a single one!) in scenario 2 (in my sample code above), I have a x-axis that varies, so a fixed position with at won't really help....

Comment: The value to the argument `at` of `mtext()` does not necessarily have to be a fixed value. You can assign a variable to it according to your x-axis.

Comment: so if I do something like this mtext(x$test, side=1, line=3.5, at=x$YEAR) how could I specify at=x$YEAR that it always places it at the last year?

Comment: just found out, that I can do it like this: `mtext(x$test, side=1, line=3.5, at=last(x$YEAR))`

Answer (score 17):

```
plot(1:10,10:1)
text(c(0,6,9), -0.6, paste('hello world', c(1:3)), xpd=NA)
```

With the `text()` function you can take reference for positioning to the coordinates of your plot and you can plot several text elements at ones.

The `xpd` parameter allows you to choose between three possibilities where you want to plot your element (also available for other elements like points and lines):

1. `FALSE` :  only inside the plot
2. `TRUE`  : in the outer plotting area
3. `NA`    : everywhere on your plotting device