# How to add annotations to a 28 multi-plot case in R?

Tags: r, plot

I have **an empty platform for 28 plots:**

```
par(mfcol = c(7, 4), mar = rep(.1, 4), oma = rep(5, 4))

lapply(1:28, plot, t = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
```

## Question

I'm wondering how I could *add all the annotations* that I'm showing below to my **above empty platform for 28 plots (*a few examples showing how to add some of these annotations will get me going*):**

[image]

Comment: Set margins wider, then maybe see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906543/r-add-text-to-plots-in-lower-rightern-corner-outside-plot-area)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These annotations are always finicky to me, but as a start:

```
par(mfcol = c(7, 4), mar = rep(.1, 4), oma = rep(10, 4))

lapply(1:28, plot, t = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")

l <- rep('Very Strong\n23%', 7)

at <- seq(grconvertY(0 + (1 / 14), "nic"), grconvertY(1 - (1 / 14), "nic"), l = 7)

mtext(l, 4, at = at, las = 1, line = 1)
```

So the tricky part here are the coordinates, which for `mtext` are defined as user coordinates. We can translate `nic` coordinates towards user coordinates with `grconvertX` and `grconvertY` though. These are "normalized inner region coordinates" ranging from 0 to 1. So for 7 number in the middle of the panels, we need a sequence from `0 + (1 / 14)` to `1 - (1 / 14)`. You can use similar logic for the other text.

[image]

Adding more `mtext` calls will get you a long way.

Comment: Sure, thank you, was there a way you found `at = seq(30, 180, l = 7)` to be a good position?

Comment: I've edited to give a better option. (Sorry, I don't use base plot very much anymore.)

Comment: Sure, I appreciate it. So, how about if you wanted to put these 8 numbers: `c('1/10', '1/3', '1', '3', '10', '30', '100', '100000')` not in the middle of the panel but right at the spaces (gaps) between the panels? Oh you can see these numbers already on side 2 of the plot in my question (Bayes Factor), right?